Problem with physical rope by surface deform modifier (advice from Blender Secrets / Jan)
I followed the instructions in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDorDVcHuzc , but got weird results: The "rope" is totally deformed, stretched horizontally and in Z-direction.
Please see the screenshots at https://virtual-world-systems.net/Blender/v1-rope/v1-rope.html
In general I did not get the surface deform modifier to work as I want it to work hitherto.
I am using Blender 4.2.
What am I doing wrong?
[Edit – direct images]







hello could you please share your file?

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

Ah ok, thanks, didn't know that, sorry.

@moonboots :
https://virtual-world-systems.net/Blender/v1-rope/rope-phys-cloth-surface-deform.zip

It's a scale problem, apply the scale of your rope (CtrlA) then in the Surface Deform modifier click on Unbind and Bind again
